# Prove there are singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

> For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $\displaystyle P_{n}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$
>
> Prove: there is $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>n_0$ $P_{n}(z)$
> has 7 zeros including multiplicity in in the circle $B(0,10)$

If we take $n\to\infty$ the function will be $\sin z$

or looking at some terms we get $\displaystyle z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}$ which has one zero (?)

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Answer (score 2):

This sequence converges to $\sin$ on the closed disk centered at $0$ with radius $10$. Let$$m=\min_{|z|=10}\bigl|\sin z\bigr|.$$Pick $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $\bigl|\sin(z)-P_n(z)\bigr|<m$ for every $z$ such that $|z|=10$ and for each $n>n_0$. Finally, apply Rouché's theorem in order to deduce that $\sin$ and $P_n$ have the same number of zeros (counting multiplicities) in the regien that you are interested in. The zeros of $\sin$ in that region are $0$, $\pm\pi$, $\pm2\pi$ and $\pm3\pi$; therefore, there are seven of them.